# XQuartz quit unexpectedly

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, gulp-watch, xquartz

I very new to gulp watch and also not familiar with XQuartz. Everytime i try to run 'x gulp watch' i get this popup msg:

[image]

and if i click on Reopen, nothing happens.

This is the Problem detail

```
Process:               X11.bin [7121]
Path:                  /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin
Identifier:            org.macosforge.xquartz.X11
Version:               2.7.11 (2.7.112)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Xquartz [7120]
Responsible:           iTerm2 [4535]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-01-09 18:08:39.234 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1212)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        39B39E1B-3565-F18B-9A59-0113DE44998A


Time Awake Since Boot: 2400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        6

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
X.Org X Server 1.18.4 Build Date: 20161025
Unrecognized option: gulp

abort() called
Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81537580 -[__NSSetM count] + 0
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a71b17d -[NSKeyValueUnnestedProperty _initWithContainerClass:key:propertiesBeingInitialized:] + 180
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a71b02a NSKeyValuePropertyForIsaAndKeyPathInner + 288
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a71acc4 NSKeyValuePropertyForIsaAndKeyPath + 174
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a71aa7d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 75
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82da9d99 -[_NSModelObservingTracker analyzeKeyPath:registerOrUnregister:] + 382
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff82da9be1 -[NSController addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 64
7   org.andymatuschak.Sparkle       0x000000010024b4b3 -[SUUpdater registerAsObserver] + 159
8   org.andymatuschak.Sparkle       0x000000010024a7b1 -[SUUpdater initForBundle:] + 103
9   org.andymatuschak.Sparkle       0x000000010024a733 +[SUUpdater updaterForBundle:] + 152
10  X11.bin                         0x000000010000a081 -[X11Controller setup_sparkle] + 186
11  X11.bin                         0x0000000100008791 X11ApplicationMain + 1463
12  X11.bin                         0x000000010001101e server_main + 185
13  X11.bin                         0x0000000100001b0b do_start_x11_server + 445
14  X11.bin                         0x00000001000028a2 _Xstart_x11_server + 125
15  X11.bin                         0x0000000100002a06 mach_startup_server + 80
16  libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83e75ce0 mach_msg_server + 504
17  X11.bin                         0x00000001000020fd main + 1476
18  X11.bin                         0x0000000100001518 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83e7c5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86174578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86172341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83e7c5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86174578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86172341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83e7cefa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821bc165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821bbdcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83e7c5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86174578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86172341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.asl-redirect
0   dyld                            0x00007fff6e75d3ea dyld::findMappedRange(unsigned long) + 40
1   dyld                            0x00007fff6e76660b _dyld_get_image_slide + 53
2   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff8c47d6e3 _os_trace_addr_in_text_segment + 193
3   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff8c47f090 _os_log_shim_internal + 64
4   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x00007fff878e90cf asl_log + 324
5   libsystem_asl.dylib             0x00007fff878eda29 read_from_source + 243
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821b640b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821c6675 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 2235
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821baa83 _dispatch_source_invoke + 983
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821bb200 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1207
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821c1707 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 549
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821b9d53 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 538
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff821b9b00 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff861744de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86172341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83e7bf06 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff861774ec pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c9306df abort + 129
3   X11.bin                         0x000000010012e8a3 OsAbort + 9
4   X11.bin                         0x000000010000dfc3 AbortDDX + 23
5   X11.bin                         0x0000000100134b36 AbortServer + 34
6   X11.bin                         0x00000001001334fc FatalError + 315
7   X11.bin                         0x000000010012e367 ProcessCommandLine + 4294
8   X11.bin                         0x00000001000dbf75 dix_main + 97
9   X11.bin                         0x0000000100010f5e server_thread + 38
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8617499d _pthread_body + 131
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8617491a _pthread_start + 168
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86172351 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83e7c83a close + 10
1   libxcb.1.dylib                  0x00000001003da24e xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info + 633
2   libX11.6.dylib                  0x00000001002c25d5 _XConnectXCB + 200
3   libX11.6.dylib                  0x00000001002b40ad XOpenDisplay + 187
4   X11.bin                         0x00000001000239e1 xpbproxy_run + 191
5   X11.bin                         0x0000000100008819 xpbproxy_x_thread + 9
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8617499d _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8617491a _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff86172351 thread_start + 13

Thread 6 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x000070000029fc38  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000007207  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000070000029fc60  rsp: 0x000070000029fc38
   r8: 0x0a58444474726f62   r9: 0x000000010016abbe  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000001  r13: 0x00000001005fb400  r14: 0x00007000002a0000  r15: 0x0000000000000003
  rip: 0x00007fff83e7bf06  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff72dcd008

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading `x` from the command line. It doesn't belong there -- `gulp` isn't an X11 application, and even if it were, you wouldn't need to include `x` in the command to run it under XQuartz.